# While loop in Javascript with a Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to write the Pseudocode given here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring with javascript using  node-oauth https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth. However I am afraid because of the nature of the callback functions the cursor is never assigned to the next_cursor and the loop just runs forever. Can anyone think a workaround for this?

```
module.exports.getFriends = function (user ,oa ,cb){
  var friendsObject = {};
  var cursor = -1 ;
  while(cursor != 0){
    console.log(cursor);
      oa.get(
        'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=' + cursor + '&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false'
        ,user.token //test user token
        ,user.tokenSecret, //test user secret
        function (e, data, res){
          if (e) console.error(e);
          cursor = JSON.parse(data).next_cursor;
          JSON.parse(data).users.forEach(function(user){
            var name = user.name;
            friendsObject[name + ""] = {twitterHandle : "@" + user.name, profilePic: user.profile_image_url};
          });        
          console.log(friendsObject);   
        }
      );
    }  
  }
```

Comment: looking into this right now..  http://geekabyte.blogspot.com/2013/04/callback-functions-in-loops-in.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose your code is wrapped in a function, I'll call it `getFriends`, basically it wraps everything inside the loop.

```
function getFriends(cursor, callback) {
  var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=' + cursor + '&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false'
  oa.get(url, user.token, user.tokenSecret, function (e, data, res) {
    if (e) console.error(e);
    cursor = JSON.parse(data).next_cursor;
    JSON.parse(data).users.forEach(function(user){
      var name = user.name;
      friendsObject[name + ""] = {twitterHandle : "@" + user.name, profilePic: user.profile_image_url};
    });        
    console.log(friendsObject);
    callback(cursor); 
  });
}
```

In nodejs all io is done asynchronously, so you will loop a lot more than needed, before actually changing `cursor`, what you need is  loop only when you receive a response from the Twitter API, you could do something like this:

```
function loop(cursor) {
  getFriends(cursor, function(cursor) {
    if (cursor != 0) loop(cursor);
    else return;
  });
}
```

You start it by calling `loop(-1)`, of course this is just one way of doing it.

If you prefer you could use an external library, like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: should I also pass cursor in get friends ? getFriends(cursor, callback)?

Comment: or cursor should be initialized in the global space?

Comment: Ah yeah you're right I forgot it, sorry I can't test your code right now. I edited my answer to add that.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni , how do I use async in front-end?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for this. It's made for situations like yours and handles concurrency and execution for you. You will simply end up writing something that does the same thing as async, only yours will not be as tested.

Comment: which method would be useful for this in async? I am definitely going to look into this

Comment: i guess its the whilst(test, fn, callback) function

Comment: Yes, whilst should be fine in this case.