# While loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, async.js

I am exploring the node.js async library to implement cursoring (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring) in node.js.

`whilst` looks like the function that I am looking for but my case is a little more different. Each time I make a `GET` request I have to wait to get a response and then change the cursor value.

In `async` documentation this is the example thats given for `whilst`

```
var count = 0;

async.whilst(
    function () { return count < 5; },
    function (callback) {
        count++;
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    },
    function (err) {
        // 5 seconds have passed
    }
);
```

I tried doing something like its to implement twitter cursor navigation but doesnt it doesnt seem to work:

```
async.whilst(
      function(){return cursor != 0},
      function(callback){
          oa.get(
                'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=' + cursor + '&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false'
                ,user.token //test user token
                ,user.tokenSecret //test user secret
                ,function (e, data, res){
                  if (e) console.error(e);
                  console.log("I AM HERE");
                  cursor = JSON.parse(data).next_cursor;
                }
          )
      },
      function(){
          console.log(cursor);//should print 0
      }
)
```

EDIT:
the console.log("I AM HERE") in my get request callback gets called only once, and nothing happens after that..

I dont think the function in the middle is supposed to have a callback that changes the counter and `whilst` only works if the counter is changed in the actual function not on its callback..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156937/while-loop-in-javascript-with-a-callback/18158547#comment26655506_18158547 an answer without using async was given here..

Comment: Can you elaborate on how "it doesnt seem to work?" What error do you see when running the script?

Comment: With regards to your edit, it is fine having the callback modify the `counter` variable. Can you try printing `data` in the callback to see what response you are getting from twitter?

Comment: data prints what its supposed to print, 20 twitter users and {"next_cursor":1442041778886213517,"next_cursor_str":"1442041778886213517","previous_cursor":0,"previous_cursor_str":"0"}

Comment: Add `callback();` to the end of the callback you are passing to `oa.get()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35298/discussion-between-gorkem-yurtseven-and-george-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.whilst` uses callbacks to know when your 'worker' function is done processing, so remember to always call the `callback` parameter that `async.whilst` passes to the function that you give it as its second parameter when you are ready for the next cycle of the 'loop'.

Answer (score 0):

I think what what is missing is a callback from within "process" function

something like:

```
async.whilst(
      function(){return cursor != 0},
      function(callback){
          oa.get(
                'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=' + cursor + '&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false'
                ,user.token //test user token
                ,user.tokenSecret //test user secret
                ,function (e, data, res){
                  if (e) console.error(e);
                  console.log("I AM HERE");
                  cursor = JSON.parse(data).next_cursor;
                  callback(null, cursor );
                }
          )
      },
      function(){
          console.log(cursor);//should print 0
      }
)
```

notice the null as first param seance err is kind of a standard.

Hope this help someone. 
Regards